# Animating SVG paths without directly using the SVG code on the page - Too many DOM elements issue

Tags: html, performance, animation, dom, svg

I'm working on a landing page that has some nice SVG's that I have to animate.

The SVG's are fairly complex and when directly putting them into the HTML Chrome is giving me warnings for high level of DOM elements.

I only want to do some simple animations (that part is fine) but is there any way to get around the high dom element issue? I know you can't target the paths with JS or CSS when using an img tag.

Comment: simplify the drawing so it has less stuff on it, or use canvas for the static parts.

Comment: You can put those paths you don't want to animate in a separate svg file, and you can use this svg as an image inside the svg you need to animate

Comment: @enxaneta That's an interesting take on this, I'll see how this works

Comment: You can put the styles inside the svg and make a different document of that which you then include as an image. I learned it from his example: https://css-tricks.com/lodge/svg/22-animating-svg-css/ (18:30 min he starts to put his styles in his svg and the rest follows)